# How to pass data from controller.js to map.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use the value of `$scope.data.range` from controller.js in map.js.

This is my controller.js

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller("LocController",function($scope,$rootScope){
    $scope.data.range=5000;
})
```

How can I use this `$scope.data.range` in map.js which is a simple javascript file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your map.js has no related to Angular, you can use localStorage to keep your range.

So in your controller, inject `$localStorage`, and set the variable in the localStrorage:

```
.controller("LocController", function($scope, $rootScope, $localStorage){
    $scope.data.range = 5000;
    $localStorage.range = $scope.data.range;
})
```

And then in your map.js, get the localStorage by `localStorage.getItem('range');`. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) you can find de doc of MDN for Storage.

Answer (score 0):

I guess map.js comes under the same angular.module('starter.controllers', []), and if you dont want to go for sessions , you could use a service or factory. Else you could use localstorage or session storage

Comment: In my map.js file there is no angular related code. controller.js and map.js are two files under a folder.

Comment: still you can go for localstorage i think

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I can give a full solution since don't know how map.js is structured but you could, for example, add a function within the map.js like `setDataRange(dataRange);` and access this from the controller. Or in general access and update anything you want from the controller (provided you have included the map.js script before the controller.js). E.g. `$scope.map = new Map(); $scope.map.range = ....` etc. Hope this helps! (localstorage as mentioned could be a good solution also, but it all depends on what you want to do)